# Filter ArcSDE layers of the TOC into a combobox

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, python-addin, combo-box

I've a list of layers of the current workspace in a combobox, but I want to list only the layers of the ArcSDE Connection, not the others I've in the TOC.
How can I filter the name of this layers?

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you consulted the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000032000000)? Post the code if you want help.

Comment: Check the examples on the [`Layer`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) class page (Example 3 in particular).

Comment: In ArcMAP, I've some auxiliar shapes, orthophotos .ecw, some wms service and a group of layers into a ArcSDE Connection. Then I'm trying to list into a combobox just the layers of the ArcSDE Connection, and I need to filter those layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Blah238! I found the solution in the exemple 3 you have mentioned.

```
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.supports("SERVICEPROPERTIES"):
                if layer.serviceProperties["ServiceType"] == "SDE":
                    layer_list = self.items.append(layer.name)
```